I tranfer taiko token through ERC20 network which is a wrong network address How can i recover my taiko token
I mistakenly transferred my taiko token from okx web3 wallet to kucoin through ERC20 network which is a wrong network address. How can i recover my taiko token, if it is possible

Sorry, do you mean you used wrong address or wrong network? What were you supposed to use and what did you use, accidentally?

I'm sorry to hear about your issue with transferring Taiko tokens to the wrong network address. Recovering tokens sent to the wrong network can be very complicated, but there might be a chance to recover them depending on the specifics of your situation. Here’s what you can do:

Contact KuCoin support: Since the tokens were sent to KuCoin, your first step should be to contact KuCoin's customer support. Provide them with all the details of your transaction, including the transaction hash, the wallet address you sent the tokens from, and the intended address. Explain that the tokens were sent through the wrong network.

Verify network compatibility: Check if the network you used is supported by KuCoin for Taiko tokens. If KuCoin supports the network, there might be a chance they can help you recover the tokens.

Contact OKX web3 wallet support: It might also be helpful to contact the support team of the wallet from which you sent the tokens. They may have additional advice or steps you can take.

Verify the transaction on explorer: Use explorer to verify the transaction details. Sometimes, having all the transaction information in one place can help support teams understand the issue more clearly.

**Be patient and persistent **: Resolving issues like this can take time, especially when dealing with exchange and wallet support teams. Be patient and follow up regularly to ensure your request is being handled.


Please note that while there is a chance to recover the tokens if they were sent over a network that KuCoin supports, it is often very difficult to recover tokens sent to the wrong network. I hope this helps, and please let me know if you have any further questions or need additional assistance. Good luck!
